# How to avoid InvalidOperationException was thrown when ChannelReader.WaitToReadAsync?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, system.threading.channels

I wrote the asynchronous queue using System.Threading.Channels.
but when I ran the program for testing, following exception was thrown at random time and worker thread was stopped.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The asynchronous operation has not completed.
   at System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation.ThrowIncompleteOperationException()
   at System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation`1.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at AsyncChannels.Worker() in g:\src\gitrepos\dotnet-sandbox\channelstest\AsyncChannelsTest.cs:line 26
```

If Exception was caught and ignore, the code is working.
But I want to get rid of the error whose cause is not clear.

here is my environment and the least code.

- TargetFramework = netcoreapp2.1
- System.Threading.Channels version = 4.5.0

```cs
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class AsyncChannels : IDisposable
{
    Channel<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _Channel;
    Thread _Thread;
    CancellationTokenSource _Cancellation;
    public AsyncChannels()
    {
        _Channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
        _Thread = new Thread(Worker);
        _Thread.Start();
        _Cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
    private void Worker()
    {
        while (!_Cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // System.InvalidOperationException is thrown
            if (!_Channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(_Cancellation.Token).Result)
            {
                break;
            }
            while (_Channel.Reader.TryRead(out var item))
            {
                item.TrySetResult(true);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Cancellation.Cancel();
        _Channel.Writer.TryComplete();
        _Thread.Join();
    }
    public Task<bool> Enqueue()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _Channel.Writer.TryWrite(tcs);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    public static async Task Test()
    {
        using (var queue = new AsyncChannels())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                await queue.Enqueue().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug, are you sure that exception is not coming when you cancel the task during Dispose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You [can't directly block on a `ValueTask<T>`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) like this:

> _Channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(_Cancellation.Token).Result

You can only do two things with `ValueTask<T>`: `await` it (only once), or convert it to a `Task<T>` by calling `AsTask()`. If you need to do anything complex, like `await`ing it more than once or blocking on it, then you need to use `AsTask()`.

Or, in this case, just use `await` in the standard Channels consumption pattern:

```
class AsyncChannels : IDisposable
{
  Channel<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _Channel;
  Task _Thread;
  CancellationTokenSource _Cancellation;
  public AsyncChannels()
  {
    _Channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    _Thread = Task.Run(() => WorkerAsync());
    _Cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
  }
  private async Task WorkerAsync()
  {
    try
    {
      while (await _Channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(_Cancellation.Token))
        while (_Channel.Reader.TryRead(out var item))
          item.TrySetResult(true);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    _Cancellation.Cancel();
    _Channel.Writer.TryComplete();
  }
  ...
}
```